# CSS text alignment and formatting issues

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center vertically 2 lines of text in a box, but I have 2 questions:

1. What is the "cleanest" way to reduce the empty space between the main `<p>` (JOHN DOE) and the `<p><span>` (born in Japan). I can play with the padding/margin of the `<span>` line but I don't believe this would be the best approach. Is it?
2. What is the best way to center these 2 lines of text vertically no matter what the height of the green box is?

Thanks,

https://jsfiddle.net/qa6yzbk7/

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes white-smoke">
            <p>Colum 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes apple">
            <p>John Doe</p>
            <p><span>Born in Japan</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes chateau-green">
            <p>Jane Doe</p>
            <p><span>Born in France</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chateau-green {
  background: #469551;
}

.apple {
  background: #6FB34F;
}

.white-smoke {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.height-350px {
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x450/E1E9EC);
  background-position: center center;
}

.intro-boxes {
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.intro-boxes p {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.intro-boxes p span {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
text-transform: lowercase;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox for centering....then using `line-height` and margin/padding resets.

I added borders for visual reference....I also took the `span` out of the `p` as it was unnecessary.

```css
.apple {
  background: #6FB34F;
  display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.intro-boxes {
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.intro-boxes p {
  font-size: 36px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;

}

.intro-boxes span {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: white;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes apple">
      <p>John Doe</p>
      <span>Born in Japan</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```